# What is the justification of imposing the commutation relation between $a$ and $a^\dagger$ in the quantized electromagnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

> singles out one mode, one quantum object, from the rest of the world. This object turns out to be a harmonic oscillator described by the annihilation op­erator $\hat{a}$. The operator $\hat{a}$ stands for the quantized amplitude with which the spatial-temporal mode can be excited. In classical optics, it would be just a complex number $\alpha$ of magnitude ,$|\alpha|$ and phase arg $\alpha$. The quantized amplitude $\hat{a}$ is neither predetermined nor given by the observer but depends on the state of the spatial-temporal mode. This state exists even if literally nothing is in the mode chosen by the observer. Then the light is just in the *vacuum state*. We will see later in this book that this "nothing" can indeed cause significant physical effects.
>
> To make all these woolly words more precise and to cut a long story short, we postulate that the electric field strength $\hat{E}$ of the light field is given by $$\begin{equation} \hat E=u^*\left(x,t\right)\hat a+u\left(x,t\right)\hat a^\dagger \tag{2.2} \end{equation}$$ and that the amplitude operator $\hat{a}$ is a bosonic annihilation operator, that is, $\hat{a}$ obeys the commutation relation $$\begin{equation} \left[\hat a,\hat a^\dagger\right]=1 \tag{2.3}\end{equation}$$

From this commutation relation, many things are proved such that $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are creation and annhilation operators in some basis (the eigenstates of $n$).
But is there a justification to this postulate?

Comment: Yes. The justification is basically the content of the first part of a quantum field theory course. See, eg, Chapter 2 of https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html. If you have studied the harmonic oscillator in quantum mechanics, what the book is essentially saying is that the field modes behave like harmonic oscillators. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method.

Comment: @eternalstudent It's more that when you take Maxwell's equations and do a spatial Fourier transform, the individual Fourier modes obey the same equations as a harmonic oscillator. Since the same equations have the same solutions, you can then apply the ladder operator method that you learn in quantum mechanics for the harmonic oscillator, to Maxwell's equations. The same thing is true for the Klein-Gordon equation, but the Klein-Gordon equation is a little simpler than Maxwell's equations so it is worth understanding the KG equation first.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically covered in intro-QM courses in the context of deriving the energy spectrum of a simple harmonic oscillator. Useful operators to define in that context (the motivation being that they raise or lower you on the energy ladder) are the creation and annihilation operators

$$ a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x + ip), \space \space a^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x - ip). $$

Recognizing that $[x,p]=i$ if we work with natural units (i.e. $\hbar =1$), we get
$$\begin{aligned}
\space[a,a^\dagger ] &= \frac{1}{2}\{(x^2 +i[p,x]+p^2) - (x^2 +i[x,p] +p^2)\} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\{-2i[x,p]\}\\
&= 1
\end{aligned}$$

What they're basically assuming there is that the modes of a bosonic field are equivalent to the energy ladder of a harmonic oscillator.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question, which is why quantizing the  $\vec E$-field should be done with bosonic operators.